# CMake - Removing an option from the GUI set in another cmake file

Tags: c++, cmake, cmake-gui

I'm creating a project (let's call it **myProject**) that includes macros and CMakefiles defined in another project (let's call it **otherProject**). Of course, **myProject** depends on libraries created and compiled in **otherProject**.

**otherProject** has an option to set compilation of the libraries in dynamic or static using the standard option command:

```
option(USE_STATIC_LIBRARIES "Build static libraries?" OFF )
```

In **myProject**, I want to force this option to *ON* all the time and remove it from the GUI so that users will not be able to change it; WITHOUT having to modify the original CMakefile. What I have done so far is force the value to *ON* by using the following:

```
set( USE_STATIC_LIBRARIES ON FORCE )
include( otherProjectCmakefile)
```

This works as intended, forcing the value to *ON*, but the option still appears in the GUI (user action however is ignored and internally, the value is always *ON*).

My question is, how can I remove the option from the GUI completely, not display it at all. I want to avoid any possible confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start reading from

```
cmake --help-command SET
```

and you will probably be interested in this option for `SET`

```
INTERNAL = No GUI entry (used for persistent variables).
```

Comment: Sorry for the long reply time, but was out on a long weekend... That did it! The "INTERNAL" flag does exactly what's needed. Thanks!